# Connect Azure Portal Backend to Local SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, xamarin.forms, azureportal

I'm new to app developing and I'm starting with Xamarin Forms and Azure Portal for the Notification Hub.

I followed the Xamarin University tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=le2lDY22xwM) to create a test app in Xamarin Forms with the backend hosted in Azure Portal.

Now I want to connect my backend to SQL server locally instead of SQL Azure DB.

So far I haven't been able to find anything in Google and I'm not sure how to approach this so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please try this:http://icebeamwp.blogspot.com/2016/09/conectando-una-app-de-xamarin-con-sql.html   Maybe you do not understand the language, but you can follow the captures.

Comment: @AbbyWang thank you, that was very helpful!